# separated by commas fro search

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am creating a table named company_Registration which stores

```
company_id  
company_name  
product_escription
```

---using php and mysql---

I want product_description column should take multiple values e.g IC chips, motors

and should be separated by commas ..

I know how to import .csv files to database and is working properly..

But, I want when user search in webpage then product_description column values should be treated as separated by commas how to achieve?

Comment: Don't do this!! You are shooting yourself in the foot but won't notice it right now. Keep your database normalized at all times. http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Comment: product_description column values should be treated as separated by commas on what will be the basis of  product_description will be separated by commas....

Comment: i got the solution a separate table is to be made for companyid and productid and performing join operation.. whole process was explained by kickstart..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to search for a match on a comma separated list (using FIND_IN_SET for example), it is nasty code to read, inefficient, prevents referential integrity and is generally a really bad idea (although not quite as bad as storing a php serialized array in a php field).

At least create an extra table of descriptions, with 1 row for each description for each company.

Possibly better is have a table of possible descriptions, then a link table with many rows per company, one for each description. The link table rows just contain the unique id of the company and the unique id of the description.

For example, simple tables

**CompanyTable**

CompanyId

CompanyName

**ProductTable**

ProductId

ProductDescription

**CompanyProductLink**

CompanyId

ProductId

Then to find all the companies who sell '*IC chips*' or '*sound system*' :-

```
SELECT a.CompanyId, a.CompanyName, COUNT(c.ProductId)
FROM Company a
INNER JOIN CompanyProductLink b ON a.CompanyId = b.CompanyId
INNER JOIN ProductTable c ON b.ProductId = c.ProductId AND c.ProductDescription IN ('IC chips','sound system')
GROUP BY a.CompanyId, a.CompanyName
```

If you wanted companies who sell just 1 of either  '*IC chips*' or '*sound system*' :-

```
SELECT a.CompanyId, a.CompanyName, COUNT(c.ProductId) AS ProductCount
FROM Company a
LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyProductLink b ON a.CompanyId = b.CompanyId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductTable c ON b.ProductId = c.ProductId AND c.ProductDescription IN ('IC chips','sound system')
GROUP BY a.CompanyId, a.CompanyName
HAVING ProductCount = 1
```

Comment: i think i want this but when user enter eg IC chips, dc motors for search but there may be company which provides both or not it depends but user should get output but company table is taking input as Product_description  i.e. if written here is IC chips, sound system then IC chips is common so reterive corresponding company name..

Comment: You just do a join. I will update my answer.